# Python creating file on timestamp created directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pycharm, operating-system

i have a problem, i want to export a file on a directory that is created using timestamp curent time, but i cant figure it how to do it

**createtimestampdir.py**

```
import datetime

import os


def createdir():
    now = datetime.datetime.today()
    nTime = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    source = 'D:\GIT-files\Automate-Stats\SVN_sample_files\svnfiles'
    dest = os.path.join(source+nTime)
    if not os.path.exists(dest):
        os.makedirs(dest) createdir()
```

This is the script that i use to create the directory

And this is the main script,

```
import pandas as pd
from timestampdirectory import  createdir

print("-------------------------------------------------------")
print("Output.csv FILE")
print("-------------------------------------------------------")
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\GIT-files\Automate-Stats\SVN_sample_files\sample_svn_input.txt", sep = '|')
df.columns = ['groups']
df['New Columns'] = df['groups'].apply(lambda x : x.split('=')[0])
df['groups'] = df['groups'].apply(lambda x : ' '.join(x.split('=')[1:]))
df['groups'] = df['groups'].apply(lambda x : x.split(','))

df = df.explode('groups')
df.rename(columns = {'groups':'users', 'New Columns':'Groups'}, inplace = True)
df["users"] = df["users"].str.strip()
print(df)
createdir()
df.to_excel("os.makedirs(dest)\sample_svn_input_update.xlsx", index=False)
```

what i want, is like after i use the createdir() function to create the dir.
I want to
`df.to.excel(in the directory that i created + \sample_svn_input_update.xlsx + index=False)`

I tried hundreds of things but idk how to do it if you can help me .

Comment: so the question is creating a folder and then creating a dataframe and writing this to a folder. Which part is not working and what is the error please ?   Also see this for question asking:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use `pathlib` to make this OS agnostic (Unix, Windows, etc) and a little cleaner. It also gives you access to a wide array of path objects.

You want to do the following:

- Create a new directory with the current date if it does not exist.
- Write your Excel file there.

---

```
from pathlib import Path, PosixPath
from datetime import datetime

def create_date_directory(path : str) -> PosixPath:

    now = datetime.datetime.today()
    nTime = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

    if not Path(path).joinpath(nTime).exists():
      Path(path).joinpath(nTime).mkdir(parents=True)
    
    return Path(path).joinpath(nTime)
```

---

```
### main script ###

from timestampdirectory import create_date_directory


target_dir = create_date_directory(r'D:\GIT-files\Automate-Stats\SVN_sample_files\svnfiles')

### your code ###

df.to_excel(target_dir.joinpath('sample_svn_file.xlsx'),index=False)
```

Comment: Quick spelling error reminder (74 of these potentially in your post history). "Lets" has two usages - one is pertaining to permission, as in "my cat lets me stroke her". The other is a declarative statement about what we are about to do: "let's try some code". It is a contraction of the phrase "Let us".

Comment: Because there are two ways to spell this word, "lets" won't appear as a misspelling in your spell-checker software. A good rule of thumb then is to read the word to yourself when you use it, and see if "let us" is the meaning that you intend. If it is, then either use the long form, or use an apostrophe.

Comment: thanks @halfer I actually don't use a spell checker - maybe I should. My University professor gave me the same advise (about minding my spelling) during my dissertation planning - guess I'm still yet to heed her lesson!

Comment: Your university professor gave you the same **advice** (advice is the noun, advise is the verb). Yes please to that spelling checker - misspelling can be overlooked in chatrooms and forums, but not here. Think of Stack Overflow as being a bit like wiki documentation. 

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding double slashes to the path. Windows usually works with "\" in strings - escape character.

Change createddir func to:-

```
def createdir():
    now = datetime.datetime.today()
    nTime = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    source = 'D:\\GIT-files\\Automate-Stats\\SVN_sample_files\\svnfiles'
    dest = os.path.join(source+nTime)
    if not os.path.exists(dest):
        os.makedirs(dest) 
    return dest
```

Change last 2 lines in Main script to:-

```
import pandas as pd
from timestampdirectory import  createdir

print("-------------------------------------------------------")
print("Output.csv FILE")
print("-------------------------------------------------------")
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\GIT-files\Automate-Stats\SVN_sample_files\sample_svn_input.txt", sep = '|')
df.columns = ['groups']
df['New Columns'] = df['groups'].apply(lambda x : x.split('=')[0])
df['groups'] = df['groups'].apply(lambda x : ' '.join(x.split('=')[1:]))
df['groups'] = df['groups'].apply(lambda x : x.split(','))

df = df.explode('groups')
df.rename(columns = {'groups':'users', 'New Columns':'Groups'}, inplace = True)
df["users"] = df["users"].str.strip()
print(df)
destination_path = createdir()
df.to_excel("{0}\\sample_svn_input_update.xlsx".format(destination_path), index=False)
```